# Get the name/type of a backbone model

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-routing, backbone-model

I have a somewhat generic view that can except 6 different types of models.

I create the view and pass in the model like this:

```
 var view = new MyView({
                model: myModelType  //can be 1 of 6 different model types
 });
```

In the view, I need to display a subview, but only if the model is not of a certain type.

In the view, I only refer to the models like 'this.model'.  Is there a way to figure out the type of model that was passed in?

I tried this but I get a warning:

```
if (this.model != ModelTypeA) { do stuff }
```

The warning was: *Using a variable without declaring it is not allowed in script mode.*

I also tried:

```
if (!this.model instanceof ModelTypeA)
```

But I get the same warning.

Is there a trick to getting the model type/name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um i tried it out and it looks right to me, are you using `new`?

```
var A = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var B = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var AA = A.extend({});

new A() instanceof Backbone.Model
> true
new AA() instanceof Backbone.Model
> true
new AA() instanceof A
> true
new A() instanceof B
> false
new B() instanceof A
> false
```